# Download file from Amazon S3 with flutter

Tags: amazon-s3, flutter

I do not have much experience with flutter, what I would like to know is if there is any way to download a video of amazon s3 and save the file in the memory of the cell phone, thanks

This is the url of the video "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/videos.ecuestre.digital/165-3745-40957-1.mp4"

Comment: Did you get an answer? If you did, please write your answer down. If not, you could ask this question a little more open. The answer should be the same for any video file from url.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I downloaded a binary file in flutter :
In your pubspec.yaml, add

```
path_provider: ^0.2.2
```

includes :

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

code :

```
static var httpClient = new HttpClient();
Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String filename) async {
  var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  var response = await request.close();
  var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  return file;
}
```

The function consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes() comes from the flutter docs :
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes.html

*Note: Edited to [more concise version from Simon Lightfoot](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/6f502205aca15e3cbf461df879673b56)*

Comment: Hey, I have to make my bucket public to download via url right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aws resources you can use the Amplify framework to interact with your environment. This is especially helpful if you need interact with a lot of resources. Check the flutter amplify storage [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/)